# htaccess / FilesMatch / DirectoryMatch allow .jpg .html and directories

Tags: htaccess

Navigation in my site is like this:

`www.example.com/pictures/cars/` etc

I am trying to allow only `.html` and `.jpg` in these folders, but I also need the directory to be accessible

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch ".*\.(jpg|html)$">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This code works but the content now is only accessible while trying to access

```
https://www.example.com/pictures/cars/index.html
```

and `https://www.example.com/pictures/cars/` is showing a 403 error

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<FilesMatch>` directive matches against physical files. When requesting just the directory then the "file" is essentially *empty*. This is despite the fact that Apache then makes an internal subrequest for the directory index document (ie. `index.html` in this case). This subrequest would seem to occur *after* the `<FilesMatch>` directive is processed.

So, in order to allow direct access to *directories* you can modify your existing regex to allow "empty" files. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(.+\.(jpg|html))?$">
```

This essentially makes the filename optional.

---

*Aside:* `<DirectoryMatch>` directives are only permitted in the server config (not `.htaccess`). `.htaccess` files are essentially the same as the `<Directory>` wrapper, but within your webspace.

Comment: it worked thank you!